# My Excel spreadsheet drops the last 6 lines of info when transferred from old computer to new.

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to transfer 250 line spreadsheet (Excel) from old computer to new.  Even when I use flash drive and verify all 250 lines are in the file the last 6 are not available on the new computer.  I know the file is complete, don't know why Excel is 'dropping' the last 6 entries....any ideas?

Comment: Anyone else have the same issue? Same excel (2013/2013)? Any macros / security on the file?

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  There really isn't much diagnostic information here for people to work with.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you *close* the USB drive before removing it? It seems like the write operation had not completed. In Windows Explorer right-click on the drive and select *Eject*.
2. If as, @JustAGrump suggests, it's MS Excel version incompatibility, try exporting the spreadsheet in different format, e.g. CSV (comma separated values). You might also try another tool to open the existing spreadsheet, such as the free LibreOffice Calc, which can handle a *great* variety of file formats.